# How to resolve 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django

I'm making a simple movie recommender app on django . In `views.py` it gives the following:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable on mobjs[:]:

## views.py

```
for obj in mobjs[:] :
    texts.append(obj.description)
    newrow = np.array(obj.array)
    #print 'enw:',newrow
    if cnt==0:
        matr[0]=newrow
    else:
        matr = np.vstack([matr, newrow])
    titles_list.append(obj.title)
    cnt+=1
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,max_features=ndim) 
processedtexts = PreprocessTfidf(texts,stoplist,True)
model = vectorizer.fit(processedtexts)
```

Comment: why do you have a **colon** - `:` inside `mobjs[:]` ?

Comment: check that your `obj` have  `description`, `array`, `title` keys means `obj` is not `None` and all the keys have value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if mobjs is a list or an array, because the error says that the object is not subscriptable, what means that mobjs has a different type.

You can use `print(type(mobjs))`